# group and sort | last login time of users

Tags: linux, shell-script, awk, sed

i have a csv file for login date of users

```
user1,2019-05-21
user1,2019-05-22
user1,2019-05-23
user2,2019-05-20
user2,2019-05-21
user3,2019-05-24
user3,2019-05-29
user4,2019-05-25
user4,2019-05-28
```

i need it in below format.

```
user1,2019-05-23
user2,2019-05-21
user3,2019-05-29
user4,2019-05-28
```

i tried *awk -F, '!a[$1]++'* , which is giving me first value not the last one .

Comment: @muru thanks for your response , but i don't see its duplicate

Comment: @niting There are several ways illustrated there, did you try any one of them? I'd simply reverse sort and pipe to AWK.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$ sort -t, -k1,1 -k2,2r file | sort -t, -u -k1,1
user1,2019-05-23
user2,2019-05-21
user3,2019-05-29
user4,2019-05-28
```

The first `sort` sorts the data by user and reverse dates.  The output of that step looks like

```
user1,2019-05-23
user1,2019-05-22
user1,2019-05-21
user2,2019-05-21
user2,2019-05-20
user3,2019-05-29
user3,2019-05-24
user4,2019-05-28
user4,2019-05-25
```

The second `sort` sorts on only the users, and keeps only one instance of each user's lines (the first one encountered).

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out in the comments, this has been asked before and several answers have been provided. I'd like to add one more:

```
sort -r input.csv | awk -F, '!a[$1]++' | sort
```

**Test run:**

```
$ sort -r input.csv | awk -F, '!a[$1]++' | sort
user1,2019-05-23
user2,2019-05-21
user3,2019-05-29
user4,2019-05-28
```

**Explanation:**

You already know how to print the first occurrence of the first column; if you want the last, you needn't scratch your head any further: simply sort and reverse the list with `sort -r`. As a last step, and only if you need your result to be sorted, pipe again to `sort`.

---

**No pipes:**

You can also solve this with a single command. If the input file is sorted (as your example is):

```
awk -F, '{a[$1]=$2}END{for(k in a){print k","a[k]}}' input.csv
```

otherwise:

```
awk -F, '$2>a[$1]{a[$1]=$2}END{for(k in a){print k" "a[k]}}' input.csv
```